# Explain the shell command: shift $(($optind - 1))

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I am not a Linux guy but stuck in some Script which I have to read for my Project.
So can anyone can help me what this command is doing?

```
shift $(($optind - 1))
```

Comment: As noted below, OPTIND must be in upper case and the '$' inside the parenthesis is optional.

Comment: Simplest explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26295865/140872

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`shift $((OPTIND-1))` (note `OPTIND` is upper case) is normally found immediately after a `getopts` `while` loop. <s>`$OPTIND` is the number of options found by `getopts`.</s>

As pauljohn32 mentions in the comments, strictly speaking, `OPTIND` gives the position of the *next* command line argument.

From the GNU [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins):

> **getopts optstring name [args]**
>
> `getopts` is used by shell scripts to parse positional parameters.
>   `optstring` contains the option characters to be recognized; if a
>   character is followed by a colon, the option is expected to have an
>   argument, which should be separated from it by whitespace. The colon
>   (‘:’) and question mark (‘?’) may not be used as option characters.
>   Each time it is invoked, `getopts` places the next option in the shell
>   variable name, initializing `name` if it does not exist, and the index
>   of the next argument to be processed into the variable `OPTIND`.
>   `OPTIND` is initialized to 1 each time the shell or a shell script is
>   invoked. When an option requires an argument, getopts places that
>   argument into the variable `OPTARG`. The shell does not reset `OPTIND`
>   automatically; it must be manually reset between multiple calls to
>   `getopts` within the same shell invocation if a new set of parameters
>   is to be used.
>
> When the end of options is encountered, `getopts` exits with a return
>   value greater than zero. `OPTIND` is set to the index of the first
>   non-option argument, and name is set to ‘?’.
>
> `getopts` normally parses the positional parameters, but if more
>   arguments are given in `args`, `getopts` parses those instead.

`shift` *n*
removes *n* strings from the positional parameters list. Thus `shift $((OPTIND-1))` removes all the options that have been parsed by `getopts` from the parameters list, and so after that point, `$1` will refer to the first non-option argument passed to the script.

**Update**

As mikeserv mentions in the comment, `shift $((OPTIND-1))` can be unsafe. To prevent unwanted word-splitting etc, **all** parameter expansions should be double-quoted. So the safe form for the command is

`shift "$((OPTIND-1))"`

Comment: It seems like this will only work right if options all occur prior to any remaining positional arguments. Correct?

Comment: @SteveJorgensen: Yes, that's correct. OTOH, putting options _after_ non-option arguments goes against sh / bash convention. Generally, the first arguments that doesn't begin with a dash signifies the end of the options, and any subsequent args that begin with a dash are not considered to be options. Not all programs adhere to this convention, but it makes life a lot simpler if you do. :)

Comment: @SteveJorgensen: (cont) This topic is discussed briefly in [Why do some utilities parse operands before options?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183646/88378). As Gilles' comment to Celada's answer mentions, some programs (like `find`) might _look_ like they permit options after non-options, but they don't: they have operands that begin with a dash.

Comment: Thanks for that info (& the edit) @mosvy That's a pretty unusual `IFS`, but it's better to be safe than sorry. ;)

Comment: @roaima if `IFS=0123456789`, `shift $((OPTIND-1))` (without quotes) will turn into `shift ""` which will be silently ignored (in `ksh`) or generate an error (in `bash` and `dash`).

Comment: That's a very strange `IFS`, but ... yep you're right. Thanks.

Comment: It's the sort of IFS that an attacker might inject into the shell environment if they're trying to break stuff. I mean, arguably if they can modify your script's parent environment you're kinda hosed anyway, but good shells scripts try to be resilient in the face of unexpected external changes.

Answer (score 16):

`$((...))` just calculates stuff. In your case it takes the value of `$optint` and substracts 1.

`shift` removes positional parameters. In your case it removes `optint-1` parameters.

For more information have a look at `help getopts`, `help shift`, look at `man bash` for "Arithmetic Expansion", and especially google for [`getopts`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial).